# Joining multiple thread in Python is not blocking the main

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello I'm trying to block the main until all the threads are done. Apparently even by executing the .join() method, the main sometime doesn't wait all the thread since I see in the output randomly one thread with the result == to none (see below):

```
Result of T0 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 0, 'Array_inspected': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T1 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 1, 'Array_inspected': array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T2 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 2, 'Array_inspected': array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T3 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 3, 'Array_inspected': array([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T4 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 4, 'Array_inspected': array([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T5 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 5, 'Array_inspected': array([50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T6 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 6, 'Array_inspected': array([60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T7 =  None
Result of T8 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 8, 'Array_inspected': array([80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
Result of T9 =  {'values': {'thread_id': 9, 'Array_inspected': array([90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]), 'Status': 'SUCCESS'}}
```

This implies that the main finished while T7 was still running.

This is my source code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List
import time
import numpy as np

TEST_ARRAY_SIZE = 100
THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 10

def init_array() -> List:
    result = []
    for x in range(TEST_ARRAY_SIZE):
        result.append(x)
    
    return result


def do_calculations(thread_id: int, input, result):
    print(f"Starting calculation for thread id {thread_id} @{datetime.now()}")
    tmp_result = {
        "values": {
            "thread_id": thread_id,
            "Array_inspected": input,
            "Status": "SUCCESS"
            }
    }
    result.insert(thread_id, tmp_result)

start_time = datetime.now()
# print(start_time, 'Before creating tasks.')

array_to_inspect = init_array()
# print(array_to_inspect)

splits = np.array_split(array_to_inspect, THREAD_POOL_SIZE)
# print("SPLITTED", splits)

thread_pool = []
thread_result_array = [None] * THREAD_POOL_SIZE

print(splits)

for x in range(len(splits)):
    thread_pool.append(Thread(target=do_calculations, args=[x, splits[x], thread_result_array]))
    thread_pool[x].start()

for x in range(len(splits)):
    # print(thread_pool[x])
    thread_pool[x].join()

for x in range(len(splits)):
    print(f"Result of T{x} = ", thread_result_array[x])

end_time = datetime.now()

print(f'Total time elapsed: {end_time - start_time} seconds')
```

Comment: What is: `result.insert(thread_id, tmp_result)`? Did you mean: `result[thread_id] = tmp_result`?

Comment: `insert` on a list will insert a *new* element at that position, but you already created the list at the size you wanted. Your list doesn't end up the size you expect and it's likely that you'll be seeing `None` in various places as things get moved around. In fact I'm surprised you only saw one of them in that example. Probably due to the threads executing very quickly and (usually) in sequence. You probably intended to overwrite the existing value, not insert a new one.

Comment: ah I see your points guys! Yes I wanted to overwrite the "None" element with the new one, so I think I should have used 
result[thread_id] = tmp_result

Comment: Thanks it's working now: I didn't spot a stupid issue like this, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Question is solved, I'm not sure how to mark it solved I have no buttons for doing this